# Specify default value for a reference type

Tags: c#

As I understand default(object) where 'object' is any reference type always returns null, but can I specify what a default is? For instance, I want default(object) == new object();

Comment: No, it's not possible. Can you tell us the end goal here, i.e. why you would want this feature?

Comment: No. And why would you need to do that? If the object is null, simply assign a new one!

Comment: Just to be able to say FirstOrDefault() and never get a null. Guess I'll just write a new extension method then.

Comment: In that case, do `mySequence.FirstOrDefault(predicate) ?? fallback`. Alternatively, you can write / find implementations for `FirstOrFallBack`, e.g. from Zen LINQ extensions.

Comment: @Ani, sure. Just don't want to do that more than once. My question is more out of curiosity than practicality.

Comment: Re: your comment, another possibility is `mySequence.Where(predicate).DefaultIfEmpty(fallback).First()`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No.  `default(type)` will always return the same thing - a "zero'ed out" version of that type.  For a reference type, this is a handle to an object that is always set with a value of zero - which equates to `null`.   For a value type, this is always the struct with all members set to zero.

There is no way to override this behavior - the language specification is designed this way.

---

Edit: As to your comment:

> Just to be able to say `FirstOrDefault()` and never get a null.

I would not recommend this in any case.  Users expect `FirstOrDefault()` to return `null` on failure.  It would be better to write your own extension method:

```
static T FirstOrNewInstance<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence) where T : class, new()
{
     return sequence.FirstOrDefault() ?? new T();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Sorry, I'm not Jon Skeet...

But anyway, the answer is "no you can't"

Comment: Normally Jon Skeet explains why (or why not in this case) :)

Comment: @PostMan, like I said, I'm not Jon Skeet ;). Anyway, I don't think there's anything to explain here... it's just not possible.

Comment: Just make it up, you'll be fine :) But yes, I agree, there is no explanation other than you can't. (other than it's a design decision)

Comment: Jon Skeet will give the quick answer first (as in "no, you can't") in order to come with an answer first, and then edit the answer to include the why.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this, it will call parameterless constructor

```
    public static T NewInstanceByType<T>(Type type) => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```