# 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' in C# linq to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, nullpointerexception

this is the line of code where it shows the error

```
var physician = (from userAccounts in myDb.Physicians
                            where userAccounts.Phy_UserName == txtUserName.Text
                            select userAccounts).FirstOrDefault();

            setFirstName(physician.Phy_FName);
```

But in my setter I have a pre condition that if it's a null value it wouldn't do anything but how come it still shoes that error? here's my setters code

```
public void setFirstName(string fName) {
            if (fName == null)
            {
            }
            else {
                firstName = fName;
            }
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var physician = (from userAccounts in myDb.Physicians
                            where userAccounts.Phy_UserName == txtUserName.Text
                            select userAccounts).FirstOrDefault();

if(physician != null)
{
  setFirstName(physician.Phy_FName);
}
else
{
  //Throw Error or any any other processing as needed.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that your physician query returns `null`.

You're then attempting to call a property, `Phy_FName`, on a `null` value.

Checking for a `null` value in your `setFirstName` method will not protect you in this case, because `Phy_FName` isn't what's `null`, `physician` is.

As an aside, you may also want to check that `fName` isn't an empty string in your `setFirstName` method.  You could check against both conditions by using `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fName))`

Comment: That was my assumption at first, however the FirstOrDefault should prevent against that.

Comment: no, FirstOrDefault() will return a null value if there's no results.  First() will throw an exception.

Comment: Sorry, I wasnt thinking of what the default value of a reference type was. My apologies, and thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: I would also point out that if the username is unique in the table, you should use .Single() NOT .First() (or .SingleOrDefault)

Comment: As you can see on my code. I am also expecting a null value. though on my setter there's a pre condition where if the fname has null value don't do anything.

Comment: @user962206 - See my update answer.  The problem isn't that `Phy_FName` is null, it's that `physician` is null.  If `physician` is null, then attempting to call any property or method that belongs to it will result in the exception you're seeing.

Comment: @JeremyWiggins I understand, thank you. soo basically what it does is Physician object itself is null therefore other rows in it is null, and with that I am getting this error?

Comment: @user962206 - Sort of.  Imagine I ask you to read a page out of a book.  But I never gave you the book.  ... You're trying to access something on a `physician`, but you have no `physician`.  I would recommend reading the link that @John Saunders posted in the comment to your question.  I think it would be very helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I bet `physician` is null.  Are you sure you're getting anything back from the query?

Answer (score 0):

The `Phy_FName` property will be evaluated either way so make sure `physician` isn't null before trying to read its properties.

You'll need to check the value of `physician` before attempting to use it:

```
if (physician != null)
    setFirstName(physician.Phy_FName);
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify on a wrong assumption of my own that maybe you were thinking also:

FirstOrDefault will return defaults if there is one, but the default for an object is `null`. So, most likely your Linq query is returning a null value for physician. Of which you are then trying to access the Phy_FName.

Here is a SO question that clarifies this more in depth: [Specify default value for a reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066315/specify-default-value-for-a-reference-type)

Comment: soo it means the null doesn't mean for Phy_FName only? the Physician Object is null? is that it?