# Is there a clever way to handle this null object reference?

Tags: c#

So I have a Retrieve() function, which either gets me an object or a null (if that object is not found). I'm using an if statement with a boolean attribute of that object. It's set up like this.

```
if(Retrieve(index).IsForm == true) {}
```

The issue with this is that if it doesn't find an object, it'll throw a null reference exception. There are some ways around this, of course, but none that I find concise. There's a try...catch, but that seems pointless when I expect the error. I can check if the object is null first, `if(Retrieve(index) != null)`, but that seems like adding needless nesting. Is there a clever way to handle this? I thought of using the null coalescing operator but it doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: I don't think there is any more concise way to do it, no.

Comment: Conciseness is not always the best way.  Readability is generally far more important.

Comment: Depending on your situation you could use a Null Object pattern. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/11972281/1066291.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either call the method twice:

```
if(Retrieve(index) != null && Retrieve(index).IsForm == true) { }
```

Or you can break the lines apart and store the result before the if:

```
var result = Retrieve(index);
if(result != null && result.IsForm == true) { }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write an `IsForm` function to do both operations for you:

```
bool IsForm(int index)
{
    var result = Retrieve(index);
    return result != null && result.IsForm;
}

if (IsForm(index))
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The Null Object pattern would be helpful here.  It keeps your calling code clean but does add an additional class.

```
class NullWhatever : Whatever
{
    public NullWhatever() { IsForm = false; } 
}


Whatever Retrieve(...) 
{
     ...
     return new NullWhatever();  // instead of null
}
```

Comment: Jinx. I just said the same thing in the comments :)

Answer (score 1):

You could make a Nullable_IsForm extension method. Then you could check for the null condition.

```
public static class RetrieveExtension
{
    public static bool? Nullable_IsForm(this Retrieve retrieved)
    {
        if(retrieved == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return retrieved.IsForm;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your code you'd check it against `bool` values

```
if(Retrieve(index).Nullable_IsForm == true) 
{}
else if (Retrieve(index).Nullable_IsForm == false) 
{}
else if (Retrieve(index).Nullable_IsForm == null ) 
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any more concise way to do it, no.

Shortest I can think of is:

```
if(Retrieve(index)!=null && Retrieve(index).IsForm == true) {}
```

but I don't like this because it calls `Retrieve(index)` multiple times. I'd go for

```
var foo = Retrieve(index);
if(foo!=null && foo.IsForm == true) {}
```

but that is obviously not doing anything clever or more concise. It is probably more efficeint than some of the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You could put both conditions in the same `if`:

```
if(Retrieve(index)!= null && Retrieve(index).IsForm == true) {}
```

Thanks to short-circuit, if the null-check fails, rest of the expression is not evaluated.

Comment: calling Retrieve twice?  What if it's slow?

Comment: just split in two statements: `var whatever = Retrieve(index);  if(whatever!=null && whatever.IsForm) {}`