# Pass specific exception as default value

Tags: c#, exception

I'm writing a generic logging application.
The next fase is the error logging.

What I'm trying to do is create a function with a exception as a parameter.
If that's not supplied, I would like to throw a `NotImplementedException`.

What I have tried so far:

- Create a static readonly Exception object

  ```
  private static readonly NotImplementedException _defaultEx = new NotImplementedException("No exception has been passed to the log method");
  ```

And tried to pass that as a parameter

```
    public void LogError(string Message, Queue _queue, Exception Ex = _defaultEx)
```

- And pass id directly as the default param

  ```
  public void LogError(string Message, Queue _queue, Exception Ex = new NotImplementedException("No exception has been passed to the log method"))
  ```

I would like to avoid the

```
    public void LogError(string Message, Queue _queue, Exception Ex = null)
```

and the

```
    public void LogError(string Message, Queue _queue, Exception? Ex)
```

approach.

How can I achieve that the default of this param is a hardcoded value withouth specifying it in the function. I would like to declare and assign it prior to it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: An overloaded method with no exception argument?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify default value for a reference type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066315/specify-default-value-for-a-reference-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my duplicate won´t get it to the point.

Actually you cannot provide any default-value other then `null` to a reference-type-parameter. However you can set it quickly within your method:

```
public void LogError(string Message, Queue _queue, Exception Ex = null) {
    if (Ex == null) Ex = _defaultException;
    // ...
 }
```

Comment: Well I guess then if everyone says "no you can't" , it's simply is not possible. This workaround is what I thought of, but I was under the impression that there was a cleaner way. Anyway, thanks for not downvoting :)