# Default value for WebApi method parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have ASP.NET WebAPI action method that looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Test([FromUri] TestRequest request)
{
    request.Process();
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}

public class TestRequest
{
    public string TestParam1 { get; set; }
    public string TestParam2 { get; set; }

    public void Process()
    {
        // do work
    }
}
```

This works OK if the request URL has parameters specified, e.g. `http://localhost/test?TestParam1=1`. But when the query string is empty, `request` param is null, and I get a `NullReferenceException` in my method.

Is there a way  to tell WebApi to always use an instance of `new TestRequest()` as a method parameter, even if the query string is empty?

Comment: There is no automatic way to do this without creating a custom binder specific for web api. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/4066357/1260204 if you were thinking of using `default(TestRequest)` in your method signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define a custom model binder:

   ```
   public class TestRequestModelBinder : System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder
   {
       public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext,
                             System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
       {
           if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(TestRequest)) return false;

           bindingContext.Model = new TestRequest();

           var parameters = actionContext.Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();   

           typeof(TestRequest)
               .GetProperties()
               .Select(property => property.Name)
               .ToList()
               .ForEach(propertyName =>
               {
                   var parameterValue = parameters[propertyName];

                   if(parameterValue == null) return;      

                   typeof(TestRequest).GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(bindingContext.Model, parameterValue);
               });

           return bindingContext.ModelState.IsValid;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use it:

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public HttpResponseMessage Test([System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinder(typeof(TestRequestModelBinder))] TestRequest request)
   {
       // your code
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of [Andriy Tolstoy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41185501/4840746) helped, I had to change it a little though to get some of my integer properties to work.

Here is the updated `ModelBinder` I used, in case it helps someone:

```
public class TestRequestModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(TestRequest)) return false;

        bindingContext.Model = new TestRequest();
        var parameters = actionContext.Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();

        typeof(TestRequest)
            .GetProperties()
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(property =>
            {
                var parameterValue = parameters[property.Name];
                if (parameterValue == null) return;
                typeof(TestRequest).GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(bindingContext.Model, Convert.ChangeType(parameterValue, property.PropertyType));
            });
        return bindingContext.ModelState.IsValid;
    }
}
```

The main change is to cast the value to the property's original `PropertyType`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Null is the easiest way though not right design wise.

Else you can create custom behavior using a custom model binder for your TestRequest type. You can find loads of examples for the same.

Comment: Can you point to any example of creating such a binder that would invoke `new TParam()` for any type passed into WebAPI method, not just for  `TestRequest`?

Answer (score -1):

You just need to test for `null`:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Test([FromUri] TestRequest request)
{
    if (request == null)
       request = new TestRequest();
    var result = request.Process();
```

Comment: This will surely work, but I'm looking for a way to instruct the framework to invoke `new TestRequest()`. I wouldn't like to have null checks in all my API methods.

Answer (score -1):

It's only possible to set default values to constants in the parameter list so it will not work as you want it to.

If you had a method signature like this you could set the default value to "ok" for example

```
public HttpResponseMessage Test(string request = "ok")
```

In your scenario, IMO, the best way is to set the parameter value as nullable and check against that in the controller

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Test([FromUri] TestRequest? request)
{
    if(request.HasValue)
    {
        //Do your thing
    }
}
```